# Child window share services and dependency injection

Tags: javascript, angularjs, childwindow

I am writing an AngularJS application that needs to be distributed in two browser windows. **Is it possible to have an application span both windows, i.e. have the same services, dependency injection etc. available in both windows? If not, is it possible to share a service between two different Angular apps?**

The reason it should be placed in two separate windows is that we are replacing a desktop application that worked this way, and most user have dual-screen setups for working with this app. So it is not one window and a popup, rather two different views of the same data. Data that is updated in one window should immediately update in the other; my idea is to place common data in services, and have the controllers in the different windows use `$watch` on data in the service.

Comment: so, I think you should play with 2 controllers then. I mean the main window can have a controller and the pop window can have another controller. and your these 2 controller can be attached with the same app module. This may help.